# ajax returning json data as undefined

Tags: html, jquery, json, ajax, undefined

when i run below code.
it makes error and alert "fail error:StntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 data:undefined"
what is the problem ??

```
$("#a").click(function () {
  st_dt = $("#st_dt").val();
  end_dt = $("#end_dt").val();
  lot_cd = $("#lot_cd").val();
  var obj = { st_dt: st_dt, end_dt: end_dt, lot_cd: lot_cd };
  var json_1 = JSON.stringify(obj);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '{{ url_for("get_operid") }}',
    data: json_1,
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (data) {
      alert("Success\n" + data);
    },
    error: function (request, status, error, data) {
      alert("fail\n" + "error:" + error + "\n data:" + data);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This needs a lot more detail, but it sounds like your server is returning xml; this usually happens when  you have a 500 error on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code it looks like a Laravel API request using Blade Template or the Function url_for is in Flask... In either case

> That means the response for the api request is HTML string instead of
> a json response...

i.e. The API request is returning a login page or some HTML page...

To check the response you can open the Chrome Devtools in the Network tab check the response of the API...

Comment: you mean alert(data) returning output of function in python flask ? not json ( {"st_dt":st_dt,"end_dt":end_dt,"lot_cd":lot_cd} ) ?

Comment: then why syntax error occur ?? it failed before run python function.

Comment: @임성빈 Yes it is returning HTML ... which starts with <... hence the error

Comment: thank you for your answer. i used form before using ajax. so i returned render_template, which contain html name. so it returned html code... i fixed code. now it run well...

Answer (score 0):

what you can try is :

```
var obj = { st_dt: st_dt, end_dt: end_dt, lot_cd: lot_cd };
console.log(obj);
var json_1 = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(json_1);
```

Then See in browser console what is your object and if the JSON converting your object properly.

If that is ok , Your request should be done currectly. And try to see what are the data you getting as response with:

```
success: function (data) {
      consoel.log('response below');
      console.log(data);
 }
```

You will find the error. I hope.

Comment: obj, json_1 are normal.

Comment: ajax makes error...

Comment: You can check your browser network tab to se whats happening on request event.  1. what is your url. 2. what you are sending.  3. what you are getting back.